# error while adding jre in the jre library in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Cannot invoke "java.io.File.equals(Object)" because "installLocation" is null

whenever I select [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xPcB.png)the add JRE systems library option i get this error

Comment: Did you delete or change any of the settings in Eclipse?

Comment: yes, i did while adding alternative path. do you have solution for this problem?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: Which versions of Eclipse and the JRE are you trying?

Comment: @nitind its JDK15.0 and JRE 1.8

Comment: *sigh* The Eclipse version?